# What exploit possible when GET request are forged as internal?

Tags: csrf, ssrf

Suppose I was able to bypass CSRF check. I was able to forge any GET request and make it look like it was issued by the user himself. Is the web application vulnerable to somehow to 'Client-side' Request Forgery  attack ? How may I exploit that ? knowing that I could not find any GET changing state request. Any idea please ?

Comment: CSRF tokens are not generally used for GET requests. That's normal; there's not really anything to exploit there unless the application has some other vulnerability.

Comment: There is no generic exploit for a generic web application. What can be done and if something can be done at all fully depends on the web application. If the web application allows to send an email as the user based on a GET request then this will be possible with a CSRF bypass, if it allows to fire nuclear rockets then maybe this too. Basically everything what the user can do and which only needs a GET request.

Comment: @ajedi32 like open redirect or xss?

Comment: Indeed steffen, I'm just looking for 'generic' idea of what could go wrong in such case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're emphasizing "internal" or "like it was issued by the user himself". That's normal for most cross-site attacks. Browsers have only recently begun distinguishing them from same-site requests (e.g. by the presence of `samesite` cookies), except for the optional (and often suppressed) `referer` header.

---

Assuming GET requests aren't state changing *at all*, you're probably fine. The only problems I can see are:

- Standard reflected or DOM-based XSS (where the exploit string is in the URL, and doesn't change server state in any persistent way). The correct fix here is output encoding (and optionally input validation, and optionally CSP), not worrying about whether the request actually came from another site.
- [Cross-site search](https://xsleaks.dev/docs/attacks/xs-search/) can use timing attacks (or, if the attacker can monitor user traffic, message lengths and other more-precise methods) to leak some information, if the search query is sent in a GET request. There are various ways to prevent this, although most of them (all that I know of except samesite cookies) break the ability for the user to edit the URL to submit a new search. You can fix it using standard CSRF protection (in which case it's best to make it a POST request instead of a GET, so the anti-CSRF token isn't sent in the URL), or by doing something like giving the user a secure random key (similar to the anti-CSRF token) and requiring that the URL contain HMAC(search-term, key) which is computed using JS, or you can use custom headers (which also works for CSRF) assuming you haven't done anything terribly unwise with your CORS policy.
- Probing a site a la dirbuster. Similar to cross-site search, if some URLs are guessable but can't be directly visited by the attacker (or give different results), you can have the victim try them and, although you can't read the exact results, you can potentially tell if they're "real" or not and maybe a bit more. Could be used to e.g. enumerate users. Prevention can be the same as cross-site search, but you can also just ensure there's a high-entropy (and non-public) element in the path of anything an attacker might be checking the existence of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One precision, the injected GET request is performed under the hood. I see it using burp proxy, that it happens but no impact found yet. I'm still studying your answer....

Comment: Hi @CBHacking, the second and third options are promising. However, I don't use Javascript in the payload, I just send the GET URL with parameters to the victim, and when he opens the mail, it is automatically fired. Any url ! I don't see how I can retrieve any information at least Status code ..

Comment: *Drive-by download* attack maybe?

Comment: @Sim Is there something special about this email-based attack that's different from what you can do with any web page, though? If you open a web page, it can make you send an arbitrary GET request in so many ways... DOM elements (like images or scripts or iframes), CSS URLs, meta refresh, script-initiated navigation, scripted background requests, scripted form submission... And yes, drive-by downloads are a risk if the browser is vulnerable, but so is literally any other browser vulnerability. Usually that's not worth mentioning, because it's obvious you can do it if you control the page.

Comment: The payload-ed email can trigger a GET request that is valid, meaning it contains a valid csrf cookie and a valid X-id headers etc. I was also able to trigger a remote file download without the user consent even if the content file is partially provided. Seems a Medium  impact to report !

Comment: Cookies are *normally* sent with every request anyhow. If they're flagged samesite, then they'll only be sent if the request is from the "same site" (looser than "same origin") but that's not a matter of "valid", that's just "same site". Also, you said "bypass CSRF check", but sending the valid cookie doesn't really help (in fact, the a common way to bypass cookie-based CSRF protection is to spoof the cookie). Also, downloading a file to the browser is trivial; the trick is saving it to disk outside the browser temp data directory.

Comment: Indeed, you are right about saving it outside of the browser temp directory...

Comment: "Bypass CSRF check"  is mentioned here because the website uses a somehow refreshed CSRF token in a cookie. I was able to perform two actions (very trivial) SAVE-EMAIL/PRINT-EMAIL on behalf of the victim ! using a GET from payload-ed email.